# Derivation of expression for sagging of a beam

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, elasticity

I read in my physics textbook that:

> A bar of length $l$, breadth $b$ and depth $d$ when loaded at the
>   centre by a load $W$ sags by an amount given by the expression
>   $Wl^3/(4bd^3Y)$ where $Y$ is the Young's Modulus.

How is this expression derived?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does this formula for sagging of a beam come from?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169773/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got my answer. I was not aware that this question had been asked before.